# compare two object arrays by javascript keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am working with javascript I have two arrangements that for the example look like this:

```
const arr1 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'A2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'B', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'E', 'title2': 'E2' },
]

const arr2 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'J2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'J', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'K', 'title2': 'E2' },
]
```

I would like to obtain from the second array those objects that are different either the `title` or `title2`

I tried the following but it doesn't work for me, where am I getting lost?

```
const res = arr2.filter((page1) => !arr1.some(page2 => page1.title === page2.title || page2.title2 == page1.title2 ))
```

the expected result is this for the example:

```
[{ url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'J2' },{"url":2,"title":"J","title2":"B2"},{"url":5,"title":"K","title2":"E2"}]
```

Comment: You are not looking for the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your goal, it is to first match URLs and THEN find out if there is a discrepency in the titles. If that is correct, this will get you there.

```
const res = arr2.filter(page1 => {
  // find URL match
  let page2 = arr1.find(f => f.url === page1.url) 
  return !page2 || page2.title != page1.title || page2.title2 != page1.title2;
})
```

```js
const arr1 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'A2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'B', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'E', 'title2': 'E2' },
]

const arr2 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'J2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'J', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'K', 'title2': 'E2' },
]

const res = arr2.filter(page1 => {
  // find URL match
  let page2 = arr1.find(f => f.url === page1.url) 
  return !page2 || page2.title != page1.title || page2.title2 != page1.title2;
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: the answer is correct and very similar to mine, could you please explain to me what was wrong with my solution, so as not to make that mistake and learn

Comment: In your attempt, you didn't first find the corresponding matching URL before comparing the titles.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all objects from `array1` in an object by using `url` as key and filter the second array by checking `title` and `title2`.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'A2' }, { url: 2, 'title': 'B', 'title2': 'B2' }, { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' }, { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' }, { url: 5, 'title': 'E', 'title2': 'E2' }],
    array2 = [{ url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'J2' }, { url: 2, 'title': 'J', 'title2': 'B2' }, { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' }, { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' }, { url: 5, 'title': 'K', 'title2': 'E2' }],
    keys = ['title', 'title2'],
    urls = Object.fromEntries(array1.map(o => [o.url, o])),
    result = array2.filter(o => keys.some(k => o[k] !== urls[o.url][k]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to map the one to a look up and loop over the second.

```js
const arr1 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'A2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'B', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'E', 'title2': 'E2' },
];

const arr2 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'J2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'J', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'K', 'title2': 'E2' },
];

const arr1MapByUrl = arr1.reduce((acc, data) => {
  acc[data.url] = data;
  return acc;
}, {});

const results = arr2.filter(data => {
  const org = arr1MapByUrl[data.url];
  return !org || data.title !== org.title || data.title2 !== org.title2;
});

console.log(results);
```

If you do not want to hard code the keys to check, you can loop over them with some() and compare them.

```js
const arr1 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'A2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'B', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'E', 'title2': 'E2' },
];

const arr2 = [
    { url: 1, 'title': 'A', 'title2': 'J2' },
    { url: 2, 'title': 'J', 'title2': 'B2' },
    { url: 3, 'title': 'C', 'title2': 'C2' },
    { url: 4, 'title': 'D', 'title2': 'D2' },
    { url: 5, 'title': 'K', 'title2': 'E2' },
];

const arr1MapByUrl = arr1.reduce((acc, data) => {
  acc[data.url] = data;
  return acc;
}, {});

const results = arr2.filter(data => {
  const org = arr1MapByUrl[data.url];
  return !org || Object.entries(data).some(([key, value]) => org[key] !== value);
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an object to track the titles based on `arr1` and use same object to filter `arr2`

```js
const arr1=[{url:1,title:"A",title2:"A2"},{url:2,title:"B",title2:"B2"},{url:3,title:"C",title2:"C2"},{url:4,title:"D",title2:"D2"},{url:5,title:"E",title2:"E2"}];

const arr2=[{url:1,title:"A",title2:"J2"},{url:2,title:"J",title2:"B2"},{url:3,title:"C",title2:"C2"},{url:4,title:"D",title2:"D2"},{url:5,title:"K",title2:"E2"}];

const track = {};
arr1.forEach(({ url, title, title2 }) =>
  Object.assign(track, { [url]: { [title]: title2 } })
);

const results = arr2.filter(
  ({ url, title, title2 }) => track?.[url]?.[title] !== title2
);

console.log(results)
```